# Java: Replace in TreeMap

Tags: java, treemaps

I have a Treemap:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

It counts words that are put in, for example if I insert:

```
"Hi hello hi"
```

It prints:

```
{Hi=2, Hello=1}
```

I want to replace that `","` with a `"\n"`, but I did not understand the methods in Java library. Is this possible to do? And is it possible to convert the whole TreeMap to a String?

Comment: `map.toString().replace(",", "\n");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When printing the map to the `System.out` is uses the map's `toString` function to print the map to the console.

You could either string replace the comma with a newline like this:

```
String stringRepresentation = map.toString().replace(", ", "\n");
```

This might however poses problems when your `key` in the map contains commas.

Or you could create a function to produce the desired string format:

```
public String mapToMyString(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("{");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        builder.append(entry.getKey()).append('=').append(entry.getValue()).append('\n');
    }
    builder.append('}');
    return builder.toString();
}

String stringRepresentation = mapToMyString(map);
```

Comment: Yes, it was this I did not understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Guava has a lot of useful methods. Look at Joiner.MapJoiner

```
Joiner.MapJoiner joiner = Joiner.on('\n').withKeyValueSeparator("=");
System.out.println(joiner.join(map));
```